# Meaning of the phrasal verb collect off

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs

In [this article](http://thesefootballtimes.co/2016/01/14/the-disputed-genius-of-arsene-wenger/), there is a sentence as follows

> A joy to watch, Wenger had come in as the untrusted foreigner, paved the way for others to join, and rewrote the tactical rulebook. Out went the early long ball up to John Hartson and in came Tony Adams **collecting off** David Seaman.

What does that mean by **collecting off** here? I have searched on the Internet but I haven't found any definition of it.

Please explain for me.

Thanks

Comment: From the context given, I would assume it means "collecting the ball [from]", with "off" perhaps being jargon.

Comment: In this case, it's a sports idiom used in several sports. It means Adams scored off seaman, the goalie. It also is used in baseball where runs are collected off the pitcher. " Morris had been thrown out by Hernandez as he tried to steal second before the Coffman walk, or the damage would have been greater. The three hits BH collected off Schreiber and his reliever Tanner Mullen were all doubles." http://www.thejournal-news.net/sports/prep_sports/baseball-toppers-fend-off-minutemen-in-six-innings/article_ffb753ae-0f6c-11e7-9659-8739c48c2120.html

Comment: The basic sentence should have "rewritten" instead of "rewrote."

Answer (score 3):

It's not a phrasal verb. "Off" is a variant of "from" in some English dialects, after verbs such as "get", "buy" and "hear". I don't remember hearing it with "collect", but it's a natural extension.

OED, s.v. **off**, *adv*., *prep*., *n*., and *adj*:

> **B**. *prep*.
>
> 3. a. Of a source: from the charge or possession of; esp. with *take*, *buy*, *borrow*, *hire*, etc. Also expressed by FROM *prep*.   Cf. OF
>    *prep*.   Now chiefly *colloq*.

Comment: I +1'd, but I think this answer would be better with sources.

Comment: Citation added, @DogLover

Comment: "Off" in this case means *chargeable to*. The goalie is charged with allowing the score. The pitcher is charged with allowing the hits or runs.